# Zxing QR Code android eclipse. Class which the decoded QR code is displayed?

Tags: android, eclipse, text, qr-code, zxing

I currently implemented zxing on eclipse. I would just like to ask where i could find the codes where the decoded QR code text is being outputted? I cant seem to find which part of the zxing library the output of the scanned QR code is displayed on the mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in `android/`, which I presume you have copied and pasted into your project. Please don't do this; we discourage it strongly. Write your own app and use pieces of the project as needed. See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Ohhh, thanks. so this would be implemented on my own app. Is there some steps i could follow to create my own and use only the qr code application library?